# Zefram Cochrane in Star Trek Books

Tags: star-trek

Are any Star Trek books focused on Zefram Cochrane or is he at least in any books and if so which ones?

Comment: You mean other than the novelizations of movies (*First Contact*) or episodes (TOS: "Metamorphosis")?

Comment: a good one is "Federation" if you can stand contradictions with First Contact - https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Federation_(novel)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A quick scan of the [Zefram Cochrane page](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Zefram_Cochrane) on [Memory Beta](https://memory-beta.fandom.com/wiki/Main_Page) finds references to the following books he appears in:

- [*Metamorphosis*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1407482.Star_Trek_7) (TOS episode novelization)
- [*First Frontier*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/8063876-first-frontier) (TOS novel)
- *A Warp in Space*, Star Trek #49 (TOS comic)
- [*Federation*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6461974-federation) (TNG novel)
- [*Imzadi*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/217890.Imzadi) (TNG novel)
- [*First Contact*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1822998.Star_Trek) (TNG movie novelization)
- [*Honor Bound*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1915250.Honor_Bound) (DS9 novel)

Note that I'm ignoring reference works (like the [*Star Trek: The Next Generation Technical Manual*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/146129.Star_Trek)) and other books (like [*NF: Stone and Anvil*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/377264.Stone_and_Anvil)) where he is mentioned but doesn't appear as a character.

A scan of his [Memory Alpha page](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Zefram_Cochrane) and his [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zefram_Cochrane) don't turn up any more, nor does a search of Google books.

Comment: Note:  Searching google books for known text from pre-1995 novels doesn't get hits, so I don't know how trustworthy that is.  I did scan the e-texts I have (a couple of dozen) and didn't get any other hits.